# Deliver a java application that starts MySQL (self-contained app)

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, installation

I have a (for me complex) problem, but wil try to address only 1 issue in this thread.

I have a java application that has a MySQL database in the backend.

I want to be able to deliver the application along with the database preferebly via an installer (this is also a part I have not currently a solution).

Anyway the problem for now, is that my preference is that MySQL should not be installed as a service.
My reason is that I would prefer not to modify the machine, that my application will be deployed.
I prefer to deliver a "self-contained" application.

So if MySQL is not installed as a service, then it must be started somehow.
I know that I can start MySQL as a standalone using:

`mysqld --standalone --console`

In this case a new command line window opens and MySQL runs (I used it so far during development/code testing).

I don't know though how I can achieve the same effect once the application is deployed (and start MySQL via code at runtime).

I thought of using the [Runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) and do something like:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("PATH\\mysqld --standalone --console"); //PATH is of course the appropriate path to MySQL installation
```

But this does not seem to do anything. It just remains hunging.

Ideally I would like to start MySQL **and** also **not have a concole open**.

Is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: Why use MySQL specifically then? You could use embedded databases... There are quite a few to choose from in native Java that offer feature parity with MySQL...

Comment: Yes I know.The problem with embedded databases is that they save all the data to reconstruct the in-memory database in files that a user can accidentally delete or corrupt.I wanted to make sure this does not happen.Otherwise, yes e.g. HSQL would be a choice

Comment: You will also have to deal with other issues such as the port already being in use by another MySql installation, etc.  For a self-contained application, an embedded db is a better solution.

Comment: No it is ok.It is a special case. 1) There is no other MySQL installation 2)If the port is not free, I believe there is a way to change the port to not be the default

Comment: MySQL also stores data on disk in files that a user can accidentally delete or corrupt. I don't see how MySQL makes it safer...

Comment: @Romain:Ok but it does not store the scripts to create whole the DB in text files, along with the actual data etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [MySQL Connector/MXJ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-mxj.). You can download it from [here](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/mxj/).It gives complete control over start and stop of database.Once you download and extract the zip, check ConnectorMXJObjectTestExample.java under 'src' folder. It will give you complete idea.

Comment: +1.This is interesting.I tried the example and mysql seems to start but I could not find my tables.It seems to create its own DB somehow.Have to look into this more, but have you used this before?I see it creates many scripts and files and exe in a user specified directory as "Database" directory

Comment: Also it seems that the `mysqld` that get started can not be stoped but manually killed

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to make your life hard? Don't use MySQL, instead use an [Embedded Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database), such as:

- [H2](http://www.h2database.com/)
- [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/)
- [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)

Comment: :Thanks for the reply.I have used embedded DB before.I think it is more appropriate for usage of the application and not storage of the end-users data.Also I feel worried by the fact that they recreate everything from text scripts.In any case, this is a special case. I want to deliver a small tool to a third party that is not much "knowledgeble" in computers and I feel safer using MySQL.May be I worry to much though...But what I need I hope is possible

Comment: I think couple of options come to my mind 1) do a remote install for them as it is a one time task or better yet 2) Find a hosting site for them for availability and security reasons as hosting is rather cheap some of them even have phpAdmin account access to them.